# this.props.editorState.isInCompositionMode is not a function error in Draft.js of react

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

My objective is to initialize [Draft.js](https://draftjs.org/) editor with the HTML which is retrieved from DB. Whenever I try to initialize editor, its throwing an error:

`this.props.editorState.isInCompositionMode is not a function`

For converting Draft.js contents into HTML, I have used, [draft-js-export-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-export-html) and for converting back to editorState object I have used [draft-js-import-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-import-html).

I have mentioned code below which I have used:

**Editor.js**

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            editorState: this.props.setEditorState,
         }
    }
    render(
       <Editor
            placeholder={"Please give details of news..."}
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
            keyBindingFn={this.keyBindingFunction}
            onChange={this.onChange} />
       );
```

**MainBody.js**

```
<EditComp setEditorState={stateFromHTML(response.data[i].htmlDesc)} />
```

Error that I have got in console is given below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.editorState.isInCompositionMode is not a function
    at DraftEditor._showPlaceholder (static/js/0.chunk.js:80878)
    at DraftEditor._renderPlaceholder (static/js/0.chunk.js:80882)
    at DraftEditor.render (static/js/0.chunk.js:80943)
    at finishClassComponent (static/js/0.chunk.js:153826)
    at updateClassComponent (static/js/0.chunk.js:153781)
    at beginWork$1 (static/js/0.chunk.js:155510)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (static/js/0.chunk.js:135702)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (static/js/0.chunk.js:135751)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (static/js/0.chunk.js:135804)
    at beginWork$$1 (static/js/0.chunk.js:161088)
    at performUnitOfWork (static/js/0.chunk.js:160014)
    at workLoopSync (static/js/0.chunk.js:159987)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (static/js/0.chunk.js:159576)
    at static/js/0.chunk.js:147628
    at unstable_runWithPriority (static/js/0.chunk.js:187261)
    at runWithPriority$2 (static/js/0.chunk.js:147574)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (static/js/0.chunk.js:147623)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (static/js/0.chunk.js:147611)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (static/js/0.chunk.js:159730)
    at discreteUpdates (static/js/0.chunk.js:136807)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (static/js/0.chunk.js:141282)
```

Is there any mistake that I have been making? Whats the reason of throwing that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one thing was missing. `EditorState.createWithContent()` needed. `MainBody.js` file code is edited with following code:

```
var contentState = stateFromHTML(this.props.setEditorState);

this.state = {
editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(contentState)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using console log to see what is the result of stateFromHTML(response.data[i].htmlDesc).

As I see it you are expecting it to be an object with the function isInCompositionMode which it clearly does not contain.

Try finding where you are invoking isInCompositionMode.

From the naming setEditorState indicates it is a function and you are setting it to be you state "editorState" (not invoking it) therefore editorState is a function which can not be accessed like an object.

Generally, I'd say you provide insufficient data for an answer to be provided.

Comment: I have edited question and added the error. isInCompositionMode() method is part of React not in my project.